# Search for an PHP array element

Tags: php, search, element

I have:

- Wordpress custom post types;
- Two hotels registered in the custom Wordpress admin area;
- A variable named `$hotels` which get the field where the hotels registered are listed;

For the `$hotels`, I'm using the `get_field` property that is works like an `array`. Inside this array, I have to get the name of the post (which is the name of the hotel). I'd like to search into the `array` the name of the hotel and print it in the page.

If I code:

```
<?php
  $hotels = get_field('produtos_hotel');
  print_r($hotels);
  $key = array_search('Ocean Maya Royale', $hotels);
  echo $key; // should display 'Ocean Maya Royale';
?>
```

It will output this mess:

```
Array (
    [0] => WP_Post Object (
        [ID] => 1113
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2014-06-11 16:18:59
        [post_date_gmt] => 2014-06-11 19:18:59
        [post_content] => 
        [post_title] => Ocean Maya Royale
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => open
        [ping_status] => open
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => ocean-maya-royale
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2014-06-18 14:41:25
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2014-06-18 17:41:25
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http://localhost/mydocs/advtour/newsite/wordpress/?post_type=add_content&p=1113
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => add_content
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 0
        [filter] => raw
    )

    [1] => WP_Post Object (
        [ID] => 1302
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2014-06-12 01:19:36
        [post_date_gmt] => 2014-06-12 04:19:36
        [post_content] => 
        [post_title] => Flamingo Cancun Resort
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => open
        [ping_status] => open
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => flamingo-cancun-resort
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2014-06-18 14:40:19
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2014-06-18 17:40:19
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http://localhost/mydocs/advtour/newsite/wordpress/?post_type=add_content&p=1302
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => add_content
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 0
        [filter] => raw
    )
)
```

Can you guys see the `[post_title]` element? So, I have to take the `Ocean Maya Royale` or the `Flamingo Cancun Resort`, but the `array_search` can not find it!

Thank you!

Comment: Should be `$hotels['post_name']`

Comment: Err, `$hotels[$id]['post_name']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_search` gives you the key for the array, not the variable. So to get the title use this variable:

```
$theTitle = $hotels[$key]->post_title;
echo $theTitle;
```

So array_search, when looking for that title, will return the key of `0`, because that's which element has that title within it.

**//EDIT//**

Because you have an array of objects, you need to change your array_search to account for the objects:

```
array_search(array('post_title' => 'Ocean Maya Royale')
```

Comment: Yeah, that works fine! It got the objects inside the array! Now I'm able to customize it in my away! Thank buddy! =D

Comment: What inspired you to changing from wrong answer `$theTitle = $hotels[$key]['post_title'];` to correct?

Comment: Reading the question a second time. Didn't account for the object in the array. You make it sound like you'd prefer the wrong answer :)

Comment: But when I used `echo $theTitle;` it was able to show the hotel name! So, what is wrong with this?

Comment: @CaioFerrari Nothing wrong, just that the accepted answer changed completely from wrong to correct, as soon I posted my `$hotels[1]->post_title;` now self-deleted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$srch = 'Ocean Maya Royale';
foreach ($hotels as $key => $val) {
    $key1 = array_search($srch, $hotels[$key]);
    echo $key . ' ' . $key1 . chr(10) . '<br />';
}
```

It is a second level array and hence needs to be iterated thru. If the search string is to be found in the specific second subscript of 'post_title' it can be hardcoded and the first subscript alone can be returned like.

```
$srch = 'Ocean Maya Royale';
foreach ($hotels as $key => $val) {
    if ($srch == $hotels[$key]['post_title'])
        echo $key . chr(10) . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic form of filtering using [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
array_reduce( $hotels, function($result, $item) {
    if ($item->post_title == 'Ocean Maya Royale') {
        $result[] = $item;
    }
}, array());
```

You can also make it into a function for reusability:

```
function searchPostTitle($posts, $search_title)
{
    array_reduce( $posts, function($result, $item) use ($search_title) {
        if ($item->post_title == $search_title) {
            $result[] = $item;
        }
    }, array());
}
```